# Why are my images not found on my web server?

Tags: php, html, css, image

I have a weird issue on my site. When I want to access the images in folders they don't show up. I've tried everything but I don't understand.

My CSS is also not working because my text is not changing. It's only working when I go to the main page.

I have 2 pages, for example, /contact/ and /about/. These don't work.

Here is the full listing of my folder.

```
/ui/images/logo.jpg (etc...)
/ui/css/site.css
/javas/site.js
/index.php
```

here my script (i removed some useless stuff)

```
<?php
$page = $_GET['page'];

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password");
mysql_select_db("page");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM page WHERE page = '".$page."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
mysql_free_result($result);

?>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javas/site.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ui/css/site.css">
<?php echo $row['page']; ?>
</body>
</body>
```

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: sounds like your relative paths are off, try using full path

Comment: "Don't show up" is vague -- are you getting a 404? 403?

Comment: Can you show how your `index.php` file looks like, anyway the parts were you include the stylesheet and the image

Comment: i get 404 yes but no 403

Comment: We need to see your code to help fix it

Comment: i cant edit the question it shows a page i get a page that say at the bottom: approve reject and improve

Comment: problem #1: sql injection - problem #2: use the slash at the beginning of each images, js, css calls like: `/ui/...` or `/images/...`

Comment: By the way, your code is subject to an SQL injection.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using full path like:

```
http://your_host/your_project/javas/site.js
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="javas/site.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ui/css/site.css">
```

The above two lines are your problem as the href= paths to the .css and .js are wrong for the contact and about us page, you're telling /contact/index.php that it can find the stylsheet inside **/contact/ui/css/** which is not correct as you want it to go back to the root folder then go into **/ui/css/**

Use an added / like so for the .css and .js files you need, see below

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/javas/site.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ui/css/site.css">
```

The added / at the beginning of src and href will force it to go back to the root directory first then look for those folders/files.